# get number of threads waiting un mutex

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, semaphore

Starting from the assumption that there's no way to atomically increase a counter AND lock a mutex (or ty to acquire it), is there any multithreading library that allows to read the number of waiting threads on a mutex?

Comment: The number of threads waiting on a mutex is not usually useful to know, since no matter what value such a function returned, it might be wrong/out-of-date by the time you acted on the information (i.e. a new thread might try to acquire the mutex immediately after you called the function).  That said, some muteness have a try_lock() method that will lock the mutex if it isn't locked, or fail otherwise... that would tell you whether or not the mutex is currently locked or not.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it was more kind of a curiosity. And I think it can be somehow useful if the mutex is actually a condition, and a supervisor thread wants to know if there's any other thread interested in such condition.

Comment: It's not called a "library", it is "debugger".  The only kind of software that can be relied upon to freeze all running threads so the result is actually meaningful and not useless in a nanosecond.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which programming language you are coding, but in C# you can [try to get an exclusive lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw) on an object without blocking, so your Mutex implementation would look like this:

```
class MyMutex
{
    public int LockedThreadsCount
    {
        get { lock (countLock) { return waitingThreads; } }
    }

    public void WaitOne()
    {
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(mainLock))
        {
            lock (countLock) { waitingThreads++; }
            Monitor.Enter(mainLock);
            lock (countLock) { waitingThreads--; }
        }
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(mainLock);
    }

    private int waitingThreads = 0;
    private object countLock = new object();
    private object mainLock = new object();
}
```